# R: Average by every N value in 3-dim matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix A with hourly data (on a monthly period) and dim [116 152 744]
I am trying to create matrix B with daily data and dim [116 152 31] 
Obviously where every dim TSTEP in B is the average of the first 24 TSTEPS in matrix A.

I was successful in creating a matrix C with monthly data with a simple apply

```
C <- apply(A, c(1,2), function (x) mean(x))
```

But can't quite figure it out to average over every N values. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take one vector only, to get the mean every 24 values, you can do:

```
mean24 <- function(x) {
  dim(x) <- c(24, length(x) / 24)
  colMeans(x)
}

x <- 1:48
mean24(x)
[1] 12.5 36.5
```

So, in your case, you just have to do:

```
apply(A, c(1, 2), mean24)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks good. It reordered the matrix from [ i  j  t ] to [ t  i  j ] but looks like I can use aperm to transpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with `sapply` and some indexing:

```
# create data

arr <- array(dim=c(116,152,744))
arr[] <- runif(length(arr[]))

daily <-sapply(seq(1,744,24),function(ix){
                             rowMeans(arr[,,ix:(ix+23)],dims = 2)
                             },simplify = 'array')


> str(daily)
 num [1:116, 1:152, 1:31] 0.451 0.522 0.407 0.536 0.432 ...
```

#### Edit:

It's also fairly quick compared with the other solution (microbenchmark):

```
Unit: milliseconds
                        expr      min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 apply(arr, c(1, 2), mean24) 464.4121 509.9772 653.9486 667.2114 699.498 1221.733   100
```

---

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                        expr
 sapply(seq(1, 744, 24), function(ix) {     rowMeans(arr[, , ix:(ix + 23)], dims = 2) }, simplify = "array")
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 164.8211 168.3295 189.8147 171.4008 196.2403 409.9638   100
```